# Map two arrays key and value to create json object in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, key

Hi guys I'm trying to map key with values in PHP to create JSON object, can someone help please.

My keys array:

```
[
    "ID",
    "NAME",
    "PRICE",
    "TYPE"
]
```

My values array:

```
[
   [
        "1",
        "Chicken Royal",
        "25",
        "Sandwich"
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "Beef Whopper",
        "30",
        "Burger"
    ],
    [
        "3",
        "Beef Royal",
        "30",
        "Burger"
    ]
]
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
[
    "ID":"1",
    "NAME":"Chicken Royal",
    "PRICE":"25",
    "TYPE":"Sandwich"
]
```

I've used this function

```
$result = array_map( function($k,$v) { return array('column' => $k,'value' => $v); }, array_keys($columnNames),$values);
```

Comment: And what have you done to try and achieve this, so far? We're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: @MarcB I've used this function  
  $result = array_map(
function($k,$v){
 return array('column' => $k,'value' => $v);
 },  array_keys($columnNames),$values);

Comment: Welcome on SO nevertheless :-)

Answer (score 5):

With [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-combine.php) you can creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.

```
$keys = [
    "ID",
    "NAME",
    "PRICE",
    "TYPE"
];

$values = [
   [
        "1",
        "Chicken Royal",
        "25",
        "Sandwich"
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "Beef Whopper",
        "30",
        "Burger"
    ],
    [
        "3",
        "Beef Royal",
        "30",
        "Burger"
    ]
];

$results = array_map(function($values) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}, $values);

var_dump($results);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(13) "Chicken Royal"
    ["PRICE"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(8) "Sandwich"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(12) "Beef Whopper"
    ["PRICE"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(6) "Burger"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(10) "Beef Royal"
    ["PRICE"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(6) "Burger"
  }
}
```